# Proving this function is non-positive in an interval (by showing it's quasi-convex?)

Tags: calculus, functions, convex-analysis

Function $f(t)$ is continuously differentiable in $t\in[0,T]$ and defined as
$$
f(t)=\alpha_1\beta_1e^{\alpha_1(t-T)}-\alpha_2\beta_2e^{\alpha_2(t-T)},
$$
where $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\beta_1,\beta_2>0$.

We know that for $0< t_1\leq t_2<T$, $f(t_1)\leq 0$ and $f(t_2)\leq 0$.

We would like to show that $f(t)\leq 0$ in $[t_1,t_2]$.

**Attempt 1:**

My first thought was to show that $f(t)$ is non-increasing in $t$. If it's true, since $f(t_1)\leq 0$, $f(t)$ does not increase and it stays non-positive after $t_1$. But we have
$$
\frac{df}{dt}=e^{\alpha_1(t - T)}\alpha_1^2\beta_1-e^{\alpha_2(t - T)}\alpha_2^2\beta_2
$$
Without knowing the values of $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\beta_1,\beta_2$, I'm not sure how I can determine the sign of the first derivative.

**Attempt 2:**

If we show $f(t)$ is quasi-convex in $[t_1,t_2]$, by definition, it has to be non-positive in this interval since it's non-positive at the boundaries.

I tried to show its quasi-convexity using the definition $f(\lambda t_1+(1-\lambda )t_2)\leq \max {\big \{}f(t_1),f(t_2){\big \}}=0$ but it led no where.

Could someone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$g(t)=e^{(\alpha_2-\alpha_1)(t-T)}-\frac{\alpha_1\beta_1}{\alpha_2\beta_2}$$
Then $g(t_1)\ge 0$ and $g(t_2) \ge 0$.

WLOG $\alpha_2>\alpha_1$ then $g$ is increasing. $g(t_1)\ge 0$ so $\forall t\in [t_1, t_2], g(t)\ge 0$

In the same way, if $\alpha_1>\alpha_2$ then $g$ is decreasing. $g(t_2)\ge 0$ so $\forall t\in [t_1, t_2], g(t)\ge 0$ so the conclusion follows.